# Extending - THREE.MeshBasicMaterial

Tags: three.js

I am looking to make a copy of THREE.MeshBasicMaterial, and create my own modified material based on it. I will need to edit the shader a little, and add some uniforms ( but I can deal with that ) .

For a start I would like to have the material work just like MeshBasicMaterial and take things from there.

This is my poor attempt (where I started), which is not working: 
https://gist.github.com/karimbeyrouti/80c00a6b3731f52fe173

How do you create a new material based on MeshBasicMaterial in threejs ?

Comment: you are not asking a specific question.

Comment: updated to explicitly phrase the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

this slide might be helpful
https://speakerdeck.com/yomotsu/low-level-apis-using-three-dot-js?slide=22

Use ShaderMaterial with build-in Shader-Chunks.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js

then you can make own extended MeshBasicMaterial.

Comment: Interestingly enough that is almost what I have done:
https://gist.github.com/karimbeyrouti/6c97dec164a11ca16bf3

Sadly, it is not working - texture in material not using offsets,repeats, in the material color, transparency & other properties are not working. Not too sure where I am going wrong here.

Comment: Note - I have managed to make the texture offset / repeat work:
https://gist.github.com/karimbeyrouti/6c97dec164a11ca16bf3

However, transparency / color / alpha are not ... still looking at those.

Comment: Making progress, this is almost good enough for me to start working on the shader: gist.github.com/karimbeyrouti/6c97dec164a11ca16bf3 
Also, some Mesh/Phong/Lambert materials properties are set to uniforms through the renderer: 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L1695

if that helps anyone else.

Comment: Got it. While this is not a direct extension of MeshBasicMaterial ( I would have to hack the renderer ), it worked well enough for me to hack a color tint to my material:

https://gist.github.com/karimbeyrouti/790d2e1a8c0137b16bae
 
There are a ton of things in MeshBasicMaterial that would not work - but it works for what I need it to. I might just have a very simple shader to do just what I need at some point instead of trying to extend MeshBasicMaterial.

Comment: @user2386872 I found your comment very useful, please consider posting it as an answer with code included