# extending three.js native shaders

Tags: three.js

I wrote some custom shader but don't want to loose all shading/lightning stuff that is in materials like `phong` or `lambert`. So I'm searching for a way to extend native materials. I suppose that for this purposes I can run `THREE.ShaderMaterial` with data from `THREE.ShaderLib['lambert']`. So this is how I do it:

```
class LandscapeMaterial extends THREE.ShaderMaterial{
    constructor(config){
        var getShader = function( shaderStr ) {
            return shaderStr.replace( /#include\s+\<(\S+)\>/gi, function( match, p1 ){
                var chunk = THREE.ShaderChunk[ p1 ];
                return chunk ? chunk : "";
            });
        };

        var lambertShader = THREE.ShaderLib['lambert'];

        var uniforms = lambertShader.uniforms;

        var params = {
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            uniforms: uniforms,
            vertexShader: getShader(lambertShader.vertexShader),
            fragmentShader: getShader(lambertShader.fragmentShader),
        };
        super(params);
    }
}
```

However this code trow an error: `WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: uniform3fv: no array`. How do I fix it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928178/replicating-meshlambertmaterial-using-shadermaterial-ignores-textures or for another approach see the source of https://github.com/yomotsu/ExtraMaterials

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853621/extending-three-meshbasicmaterial/34862278

Comment: for now I just want to recreate native lambert shader so I take uniforms from  `THREE.ShaderLib`, take code for vertex and fragment shaders from `THREE.ShaderLib` and put it in `THREE.ShaderMaterial`. Seems pretty simple. But it does not work. What is missed, why it does not work?

Comment: error comes from this line of fragment shader https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshlambert_frag.glsl#L71

Comment: finally I solved it - the solution was to add `this.lights = true;`